# How to load a images in a website faster using php

Tags: php

I am creating an image using the code below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php.

Now, I displayed the image in my webpage, localhost/home.php and fetched the image in here.

```
 <img src="<?php echo  http://localhost/imagecreate.php; ?>" />
```

and displayed correctly.

However, my problem is that, it takes time to load the website because of that imagecreate script unlike with the usual image below:

```
  <img src="images/img.jpg" />
```

Is there any other way to load the **imagecreatefromjpeg** faster?

Comment: have you looked at caching (on server side) the dynamically created images ? if they are not unique for every request, loading them from cache would be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dynamically creating an image every time. So the caching won't work. That's why it's taking more time to load. Better convert the image while uploading, to desired format and save it. Then load image directly without imagecreate.

Comment: I see. I got your point.. I am creating an image on the browser and not on the server. Do you have idea to copy an imagecreatejpg to a server using a script?